# How to store a file in memory and directly use it in Java?

Tags: java, performance, shared-memory

I'm using Weka and have saved a model and I want to use the model to do some predictions. However, I have to use C++ for my GUI so every time I call the .jar file, I gonna re-read the model and this wastes a lot of time. How can I store the model in memory and directly use it from Java? Or are there any better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JNI to use a C/C++ functionality you have in a DLL, you can store your byte array in memory "inside" your DLL code.  It is a rough equivalent to a static variable, something like:

```
// ... includes, etc

char myFile[];

void loadFile(char filePath*) {
   // C code to size myFile and store the file contents in it
   myFile = new char[whateverTheSizeOfTheFile];
   // ...
}

void unloadFile() {
   delete[] myFile;
}
```

And remember to explicitely call `unloadFile` from your java code in order to return the resources reserved in your C/C++ code

Answer (score 0):

You can use a memory mapped file in Java.  You can store what ever you want in binary format and then map there data into memory as a single operation.  The problem arises when you need to copy this data into a form which Weka understands e.g. double[] and unfortunately this is unavoidable unless Weka can read from a DoubleBuffer or similar.